# Give each row a random color in mattable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to implement a functionality in mattable in such a way that there is an array of colors defined and each color randomly show up in the background of each mattable row. I am not sure how to implement this but i thought maybe it can be done through style binding or something like that. I tried using css but that seems like a very bad idea here is my mattable code

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="srNo">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"> {{i + 1}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="routes">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Routes </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="percentage">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><mat-progress-bar style="margin-top: 20px;" mode="determinate" value="{{element.percentage}}"></mat-progress-bar>
      <div style="position:relative; top: -20px;">
        {{ element.percentage }}%
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="capacity">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  style="text-align: center;"> Total Parcels </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"  style="text-align: center;"> {{element.totalParcels}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  style="text-align: center;"> Total Price </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"  style="text-align: center;"> {{element.totalPrice | currency: 'Rs.'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </tr>
</table>
```

css code

```
.mat-row:nth-child(even){
  background-color:red;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

I need to know how i can assign random colors to each row. Right now my mattable has got only three rows and the 1st and 3rd row is showing in greenyellow color while the 2nd is showing red color.

Comment: any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it

```
heroes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
bgColor() {

}

getRandomColor2() {
  var length = 6;
  var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var hex = '#';
  while(length--) hex += chars[(Math.random() * 16) | 0];
  return hex;
}

getRandomColor() {
  var color = Math.floor(0x1000000 * Math.random()).toString(16);
  return '#' + ('000000' + color).slice(-6);
}
```

and in my html file

```
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                (click)="selection.toggle(row)" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getRandomColor()}">
  </tr>
```

I did solved the problem but when i scroll the page up or down the colors keep changing. How can i stop them from changing? It looks like that when i am scrolling the table keeps on rendering even though the data in mattable is static.

Answer (score 0):

why not include in your dataSource a new property: bgColor and use in the table?

In the tipical example

```
dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA.map(x => ({
    ...x,
    bgColor: this.getRandomColor()
  }));
  getRandomColor() {
    var color = Math.floor(0x1000000 * Math.random()).toString(16);
    return "#" + ("000000" + color).slice(-6);
  }
```

And

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
       [style.background-color]="row.bgColor"></tr>
```

See in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhmt1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html)